# window.onload not running on page refresh

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I just started using RequireJs. Only one problem. Can someone explain why the code inside the require block is not run on page refresh. **It only runs when I clear the cache**.

example:

```
require(['game','comm','misc','soundutil','sprite','gui','constants'],function(Game,COMM,MISC,SoundUtil,Sprite, Gui,CNT){

    window.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas'),
         game = document.getElementById('game'),
         g = null,su = null;

        canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
        canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
console.log('Gamestate at beginning',CNT.GameState._current);
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not look like your code is complete in your question but I'm going to hypothesize the following. What you describe looks like a race condition:

- When the cache does not contain your data, the assignment to `window.onload` happens before the `onload` even is fired, so your handler is called.
- When the cache already contains your data, then the `onload` event is fired *before* the assignment to `window.onload` happens, so *your handler is never called*.

I would suggest using the [`domReady` plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/domReady) because it is designed to handle both cases. I've never used it myself but from what I can gather from the [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload), something like:

```
require(['domReady!', 'game','comm','misc','soundutil','sprite','gui','constants'],...
```

should work. The exclamation mark is not a typo, by the way. You then need to make your `onload` handler be the body of the function you pass to `require`.

Note that `document.onload` suffers from the same problem. It is even more prone to the problem you're having because it often fires before `window.onload` does.

ETA: As Shrike says, you can also use the jQuery method of waiting: `$(document).ready(...)`. My rule of thumb here is if I'm already using jQuery (which I actually do in all my current projects), then I'd use `$(document).ready(...)`, otherwise I'd use `domReady`. The difference between the two methods has been examined in detail [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332628/requirejs-domready-plugin-vs-jquery-document-ready).

Comment: so the onload event is closely related to the data you have in the cache, it is not at all related to a domready event. I see the difference. I will look at that 'domReady' event.

Comment: The way I would put it is that the presence or absence of your data in the cache affects how quickly or how late the ``onload`` event is fired. Also, ``domReady`` is not an event, that's just the name of the plugin. Internally, ``domReady`` uses the ``onload`` event. It's just that it keeps track of whether ``onload`` has happened or not already.

Comment: but the race condition exists because it's wrapped in the require function call, right?(I mean it was working before I started using requirejs) anyway domready seems to be the best choice.

Comment: The ``require`` function certainly provides the conditions for a race condition to occur. ``domReady`` is definitely a better choice than rolling your own event handler.

Answer (score 1):

It's because at the moment of your code execution window is already loaded. So you're subscribing on an event which never fires. I'm not sure what kind if cache did you mean and why window's load fires.

You can easy fix your code if you use jQuery:

```
require(['game', 'comm', 'misc', 'soundutil', 'sprite', 'gui', 'constants'], function(Game, COMM, MISC,SoundUtil, Sprite, Gui,CNT){

  $(document).ready(function () {
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time RequireJS is done preparing dependencies and executes the factory function the `onload` could have already happened, in this case your custom handler will not be executed as it is already late (the "onload train" already left).

A RequireJS-specific alternative is to use the domready plugin:

```
require(['a', 'b', 'domready'], function (A, B, domReady) {
  domReady(function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas'),
      game = document.getElementById('game'),
      g = null,
      su = null;

    canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
    console.log('Gamestate at beginning', CNT.GameState._current);
    // ...
  });
});
```

More details about domready plugin [in the official documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload)